# Problem with reaching second normal form in a database

Tags: normalization

I'm currently taking an Databases/Database server course as a part of my education, and for this week we have been assigned a simple project to complete. I'm facing a problem regarding normalization. I thought I knew how to do it, buy my teacher is saying what I'm doing is wrong and he have a hard time explaining me **why** it is wrong.

I have four tables in the database:

```
ZIPCODE  
MEMBER  
SCORECARD  
ROUNDS
```

This question is only about `SCORECARD` and `ROUNDS`. The `SCORECARD` table has the following attributes:

```
scoreCardID (Primary key)  
memberID (Foreign key to MEMBER table)  
date
```

The `ROUNDS` table has the following attributes:

```
scorecardID (Foreign key to SCORECARD table and primary key)  
roundID (Primary key, together with scorecardID)  
shot1  
shot2  
shot3  
shot4  
shot5
```

There can be between 1-8 rounds on a `scorecardID`, and each round has five shots. My teacher is now saying, that my `ROUNDS` table is causing me to be unable to obtain second normal form, which I don't understand. What he says is, that I would have to create another table, that contains the shots, which is then linked to the `ROUNDS` table.

As I understand the second normal form is, that no non-key attribute can be dependant on any other attribute that is not a part of the key.

Can anyone verify that I'm correct, or if I'm wrong explain to why my `ROUNDS` table is wrong regarding the second normal form?

Comment: `Rounds` is not even in **[1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)**.

Comment: @ypercube is right.  Take repeating groups out to get to 1NF.  You can't be 2NF if you aren't 1NF yet, regardless of the definition/test for 2NF.

Comment: Here is a very good (and simple) guide to [normal forms](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm).